# Model a bag of liquid in Box 2D

Tags: java, box2d, physics, game-physics, scene2d

How would I go about modeling a turgid bag of fluid in Box 2D, i.e. what physics equations would be useful in modeling this? The bag of water could move when touched, but that is the only interaction. Any places equations or models would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you need it to do?

Comment: You can probably build something that behaves kind of like this but it depends on what you need it for. If it's just graphics, or if you need collision. How accurate does it need to be, etc

Comment: @bigcodeszzer It is for collision and interaction with the user, so collision is necessary

Comment: I think a series of circles joined together by small joints in roughly the bag shape you need would do this. Processing wise, it might not work very well. There are a few tricks you could do to make it faster though.

Comment: A permiter of smaller circles attached to a large one in the middle might work.

Comment: @bigcodeszzer That is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a library for this. Google's LiquidFun is quite good http://google.github.io/liquidfun/

Answer (score 0):

User99345's answer is the way I'd go to model a bag of liquid, but if you're wanting to use an unmodified Box2D library you can model it using instances of `b2EdgeShape`, `b2RevoluteJoint`, and `b2CircleShape`. Whether that's a good enough way to model it, you'll have to decide.

Additional basis/insight for this...

After seeing your question I put together a model for a bag of liquid as a Testbed demo in [my dev branch of my fork of Box2D](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/Box2D). The demo is called "Bag of Disks" because that's basically what the demo models and it's in the file [`BagOfDisks.hpp`](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/Box2D/blob/dev/Testbed/Tests/BagOfDisks.hpp). The code uses a series of edge shapes connected by revolute joints to model a deformable container and fills it with circle shapes (called `DiskShape` in my fork) to model a liquid. If you build the library and Testbed of my fork you can see for yourself how the model looks.

As a model of a bag of liquid, I'm of the opinion that the code I whipped together has shortcomings like the following:

- It must be computationally less efficient than using particle simulation like Google's LiquidFun does.
- I don't believe joints as currently implemented in Box2D (or my fork of it), can always ensure containment. That's because I don't believe joints are able to 100% prevent alternative movement of the connected shapes.
- The "bag" in the demo doesn't level evenly at it's top like I'd expect a normal bag of liquid to do.
- The "bag" doesn't model a buoyancy force that I'd expect the top of a bag to do.

I imagine things can be done from a user level to improve the model's behavior but I suspect less can be done from a user level to improve the model's speed. By user level, I mean as a user of the Box2D library.

While my fork has made many changes to the Box2D library (especially in naming), I don't believe what I've done in the demo itself can't be reproduced pretty closely using the original Box2D library and syntax as I'd said in my first paragraph using instances of `b2EdgeShape`, `b2RevoluteJoint`, and `b2CircleShape`.

As to what physics equations would be useful in modeling this beyond the equations that Box2D already uses, I'm sorry to say that I have no idea at the moment. I am interested in that however and am looking into it as well. Physics equations for this are available of course but the closest related work that I'm aware of from a Box2D user level is what iforce2d put together in his [Buoyancy](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/buoyancy)  web page.

Hope this answer contributes helpfully to what's already been said.